# Using PHP, search a string of characters for a URL and save that URL as a value

Tags: php, string, wordpress, url, replace

**Question:**
Using PHP, how can I search a string of characters for a URL, save that URL as a variable, and then delete the URL from the string?

**Here is my problem:**
I am designing a WordPress site and have a box on the homepage with the latest podcast of my client. When reading the Podcast post, a plugin changes the URL of the podcast into an HTML5 audio player. But, on the homepage this plugin doesn't work and only shows the URL unless I use their PHP short code.

**What I need to do:** I need to take the content of the post and save it as a variable. I do this like so:

```
$content = get_the_content();
```

Then, I need to parse the variable `$content` to find the URL for the podcast (should be the first thing in the string), save that URL as a variable and then delete the URL from `$content`. **(I don't know how to do this.)**

Then, I need to replace that URL with the shortcode and print out the rest of the podcast text. Like this:

```
<?php 
$podcastURL = //Code I do not know how to write// ;

echo do_shortcode('[audio mp3="'.$podcastURL.'" autoplay="off" loop="off" preload="on" controls="on" flash_fallback="on"]'); 

echo $content;

?>
```

**Things I know**
- URL should be the first thing in the string. I can tell my client that this is needed.
- URL will always start with: `http://mcmaz.co/podcasts/`.
- URL will always end with: `.mp3`.
- URL should be formatted like this: `http://mcmaz.co/podcasts/2014/08/19/Getting_Your_Home_in_Order.mp3`

**Things I do not know**
- The part of the URL after `/podcasts/` and before `.mp3`.
- User error in putting `www.` before `mcmaz.co`.

**Resources**
- Site homepage with broken player: http://www.staticchurch.com
- Sample Podcast Page with working plugin: http://staticchurch.com/podcast/getting-your-home-in-order/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = 'http://mcmaz.co/podcasts/2014/08/19/Getting_Your_Home_in_Order.mp3 Guest speaker Pastor Rick Holman over the Cactus campus';

$start = 'http';
$end = 'mp3';

function getMiddle($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$middle = getMiddle($text, $start, $end);

//Saved url variable
$url = $start.''.$middle.''.$end;
//Text with removed url
$text = str_replace($url, '', $text);
```

Comment: Thank you @Sergey6116, that worked perfectly. I changed a few of the variable calls to match my existing code; but it did what I was asking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

using `preg_match_all('/http\:\/\/mcmaz\.co\/podcasts\/.+\.mp3/', $content, $matches);` will return the matches.

Meanwhile `preg_replace('/http\:\/\/mcmaz\.co\/podcasts\/.+\.mp3/', '', $content);` will replace all the urls with *nothing*.

Then it's a matter of doing a foreach on the podcast code with the matches + with some extra work it'll be done.